# getTime() method on TimePicker control returns wrong value issue

Tags: codenameone

When `getTime()` called on TimePicker control will return 1445 from 12:05 PM instead of 725. Also, 12:05 AM is also not working properly. Control is very inconsistent when setShowMeridiem is set. Please see the attached screenshot and code.
Code:

Form hi = new Form("Picker", BoxLayout.y());

```
        Picker p = new Picker();
        p.setType(PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
        p.setShowMeridiem(true);
        Label value = new Label("" + p.getTime());

        hi.add(p)
                .add(value);

        p.addActionListener(e1
                -> {
                    value.setText("" + p.getTime());
                }
        );

        hi.show();
```

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a [minimum viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

No.

```
Form hi = new Form("Picker", BoxLayout.y());

Picker p = new Picker();
p.setType(PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
Label value = new Label("" + p.getTime());
hi.add(p).add(value);

p.addActionListener(e -> {
    value.setText("" + p.getTime());
});

hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Shai, I have updated the description and screenshot. Please advise.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Meridiem functionality, please file an issue with the code and screenshots